# Okay to use underscores in file and folder names in PHP?

Tags: php

For example using `<?php include '_blogroll.php'; ?>` instead of blogroll.php ? It helps me organize the partial files in cPanel (_header.php, _footer.php, etc.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

yes. You can and it's safe to use.